# How to keep basemap high res detail when printing large resolution in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, print-composer

I need to print a map with a0 resolution and I need it zoomed over a large area.

Problem when zooming out is that the basemap also gets zoomed out and loses labels and important details.

Basemap is from Quickmapservices plugin

How to keep the lower resolution basemap details on the print composer?